# why does the addition of byte and byte or short and short return an integer?

Tags: java, sum

I ran a Java Program where i declared two byte values let say 8 and 9. I declared an another byte variable to put their sum in it. Now it is returning an error.

Meanwhile, I declared a fourth variable of int type and it successfully stored that summation.

Comment: If you write code and you get an error, [show your code, and show the error](/help/how-to-ask)